# In PyCharm, is it possible to disable hiding style tags?

Tags: phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm

When I have a string of HTML in PyCharm, I see the style as `style="..."` and only if I click on the `...` I can see the style contents. Is it possible to disable this feature and always show style tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In your IDE's `Settings` screen (`Preferences` on Mac)
- Find `Code Folding` section
- Uncheck `HTML style attribute` option

[image]